# Why the inconsistent file extension case from airdropped photos?

Tags: iphone, photos, airdrop

I'm cleaning out a bunch of photo files off the Photos app from my iPhone device and transferring them to a macbook using the share to AirDrop feature. I'm a lil baffled at this inconsistency I'm seeing in the case for the file extension text, ie `jpg` vs `JPG`.

What could be causing this? A software bug in MacOS or iOS? Or maybe I used a different mode when taking those photos? Something seems off.

Here's a screenshot for what I'm experiencing, take for example `IMG_9286.JPG` vs `IMG_9287.jpg`

[image: screenshot of finder with the extension inconsistency]